# Parent child count- new challenge

Tags: sql, t-sql

Sorry guys
I think I mixed two requiements in 1 query.

I will re-iterate my problem.Pls ignore the above ddl:

The basic scenario for this report is:

MASTER table has a list of different line nos or (phone nos) who all have a unique account number and phone number.

We also  have a base table in our database which is a daily snapshot to tell us what nos are active on a particular plan on a given day.

So for example lets say on 12th Feb 20 phone nos are active as per base table.

Now along with the base table, I have a MASTER Table which tells us how these phone nos arrived on base was it a new connection or was it a plan change from some other plan.

And to explain the parent - child relationship, there is a leader plan (with a leader/parent code) and one phone number contains this parent code and this parent can have multiple child phone nos who all share the same plan and the way to determine the parent and child nos is through ACCOUNT NO as both parent and children share the same account no for a given shared plan.

There are in total 4 parent plans (4 different parent codes) in my database and 1 shared plan code.

In my query i need to count how many sharers belong to a particular parent in a given month and also have to count -out of total parent nos, how many were plan changes,how many were new connections and same for sharers as well.

I can count the parent/child count in my base table which works fine .

Here is the modified ddl for MASTER Table using sqlfiddle.com and here is the link to it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83843/1

```
CREATE TABLE Master_Table
    (
     BaseDate DATETIME
    ,Account_no VARCHAR(4)
    ,Phone_no INT
    ,Code VARCHAR(2)
    ,New_connect INT
    ,Plan_change INT
    );

INSERT INTO Master_Table
        ( BaseDate, Account_no, Phone_no, Code, New_connect, Plan_change )
    VALUES  ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A123', 21332, 'P1', 1, 0 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A123', 21444, 'C1', 0, 1 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A123', 21445, 'C1', 1, 0 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A124', 21333, 'P2', 1, 0 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A124', 21771, 'C1', 0, 1 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A124', 21772, 'C1', 0, 1 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A124', 21773, 'C1', 1, 0 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A126', 213321, 'P1', 1, 0 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A126', 214443, 'C1', 0, 1 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A126', 214452, 'C1', 1, 0 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A129', 213331, 'P3', 1, 0 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A129', 21771, 'C1', 0, 1 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A129', 21772, 'C1', 0, 1 ),
            ( '2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'A129', 21773, 'C1', 1, 0 );
```

My desired output is:

```
Base_Date            Parent_code Parent_new_connect Parent_plan_change Child_new_connect Child_plan_change
'2014-02-01 13:00:00' P1         2                  0                   2                   2
'2014-02-01 13:00:00' P2         1                  0                   2                   2
'2014-02-01 13:00:00' P3         1                  0                   1                   2
```

Hope its clearer this time.

Comment: A good way to ask questions about specific data and queries, is to set up test data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and link to that. It makes it much more likely that someone will understand it, and be willing to answer.

Comment: done the formatting. Thanks

Comment: I have re-posted the DDL using SQLFiddle now

Comment: Where is the SQLFiddle link? You need to share the link with us.

Comment: Links added now fem SQL fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are looking for and have a query here that produces what I think you want.. I ask that you please confirm the desired value of P2 - Child_new_connet as I get a different number. Here is the query against the data you provided.

```
select 
    M.BaseDate, 
    M.Code ParentCode,
    sum(M.New_Connect) Parent_New_Connect,
    sum(M.Plan_Change) Parent_Plan_Change,
    (select sum(new_connect) connect from Master_Table where Code like 'C%' and Account_no in (select Account_no from Master_Table where Code = M.Code)) Child_New_Connect,
    (select sum(Plan_change) connect from Master_Table where Code like 'C%' and Account_no in (select Account_no from Master_Table where Code = M.Code)) Child_Plan_Change
from 
    Master_Table M
where
    Code like 'P%'
group by
    BaseDate,
    Code
```